# PHP bitwise left shifting 32 spaces problem and bad results with large numbers arithmetic operations

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, precision

I have the following problems:

First: I am trying to do a 32-spaces bitwise left shift on a large number, and for some reason the number is always returned as-is. For example:

```
echo(516103988<<32); // echoes 516103988
```

Because shifting the bits to the left one space is the equivalent of multiplying by 2, i tried multiplying the number by 2^32, and it works, it returns 2216649749795176448.

Second: I have to add 9379 to the number from the above point:

```
printf('%0.0f', 2216649749795176448 + 9379); // prints 2216649749795185920
```

Should print: 2216649749795185827

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Pascal MARTIN's suggestions, i tried both the BCMath and the GMP extension and came up with the following solutions:

With BCMath:

```
$a = 516103988;
$s = bcpow(2, 32);    
$a = bcadd(bcmul($a, $s), 9379);
echo $a; // works, echoes 2216649749795185827
```

With GMP:

```
$a = gmp_init(516103988); 
$s = gmp_pow(gmp_init(2), 32); 
$a = gmp_add(gmp_mul($a, $s), gmp_init(9379)); 
echo gmp_strval($a);  // also works
```

From what i understand, there is a far greater chance for BCMath to be installed on the server then GMP, so i will be using the first solution.

Thanks :)

Comment: i was planning on accepting my answer to pin it at the top for future visitors :)

Comment: i'd say this is totally justified in this case, since you provided a nice summary.

Answer (score 5):

Doing 32 bit-shifting operations will probably not work like you expect, as integers tend to be stored on 32 bits.

Quoting this page : [Bitwise Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

> Don't right shift for more than 32
> bits on 32 bits systems. 
> Don't left
> shift in case it results to number
> longer than 32 bits. 
> Use functions
> from the gmp extension for bitwise
> manipulation on numbers beyond
> `PHP_INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 4):

Php integer precision is limited to machine word size (32, 64). To work with arbitrary precision integers you have to store them as strings and use [bc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or gmp library:

```
   echo bcmul('516103988', bcpow(2, 32));  // 2216649749795176448
```